# C# assembly is not being imported on

Tags: c#, asp.net

The server returning the following error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Line 9:  using System.Data.SqlClient;
Line 10: using System.Data;
Line 11: using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

The two external C# libraries that im using: Newtonsoft.json and HtmlTags are not being imported and throwing the following error on my asp.net webforms site.

**Note:** everything is working fine on my local machine but not that it is on the development server it throwing this error.

The bin directory contains the following library dlls:

```
bin\
  HtmlTags.dll
  Newtonsoft.Json.dll
  Newtonsoft.Json.xml
```

Here is my packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="HtmlTags" version="3.0.0.186" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

**What I have tried**

- Removed the references from the project and added them back
- Update the packages
- Rebuild the project

Comment: have you try copy those dlls from your local machine to the app's bin directory in your server

Comment: Are you using NuGet to manage Newtonsoft?  If not, I suggest removing those references, then get them via the NuGet Package Manager and include them in whichever solution components need them.

Comment: Have installed .Net 4.0 on developer server?

Comment: @EnriqueZavaleta Yes I have I have verified that they are the same ddls on my local and on the development server

Comment: @JeffPrince I used Nuget Package to install Newtonsoft and HtmlTags

Comment: @awesome Yes the server is running .Net 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the fact that the directory that the site was living was not properly configured as a .NET application.

Answer (score 2):

When you deploy your application, you need to make sure you include the referenced DLLs.  By default, they are not included.

Include the DLLs in your project, as well as referencing them, then in the properties, tag them as "Copy Always".